# Too much duplication of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering, is that I have to many duplicates. I am basically trying to show 1/11 tables by which bottom is clicked (list_row[1-11]), so when I show for instance table 2, it must hide all the other tables.

I believe this can be shortened by a loop or something else, because if I have 100 tables then I must copy and paste, not smart. Keep in mind that the code below is just showing table 1 to table 3. How can I prevent these duplicates?

```
// hide the tables by default when page loads
$('#table1').hide();
$('#table2').hide();
$('#table3').hide();
$('#table4').hide();
$('#table5').hide();
$('#table6').hide();
$('#table7').hide();
$('#table8').hide();
$('#table9').hide();
$('#table10').hide();
$('#table11').hide();                           

// Show Exhaust Temperature diagram 

        $('#list_row1').on('click',function(){ 
            $('#table1').show();
            $('#table2').hide();
            $('#table3').hide();
            $('#table4').hide();
            $('#table5').hide();
            $('#table6').hide();
            $('#table7').hide();
            $('#table8').hide();
            $('#table9').hide();
            $('#table10').hide();
            $('#table11').hide();  
        });

        // Show Cylinder Pressure diagram 
        $('#list_row2').on('click',function(){
            $('#table1').hide();
            $('#table2').show();
            $('#table3').hide();
            $('#table4').hide();
            $('#table5').hide();
            $('#table6').hide();
            $('#table7').hide();
            $('#table8').hide();
            $('#table9').hide();
            $('#table10').hide();
            $('#table11').hide();  

        });

        $('#list_row3').on('click',function(){ 
            $('#table1').hide();
            $('#table2').hide();
            $('#table3').show();
            $('#table4').hide();
            $('#table5').hide();
            $('#table6').hide();
            $('#table7').hide();
            $('#table8').hide();
            $('#table9').hide();
            $('#table10').hide();
            $('#table11').hide(); 
        });

// Code continues to table11.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set all your tables to `display: none` then introduce an `.active` class set to `display: block` (or `display: table`, in this case). Then simply toggle the class on and off:

```css
.active {
    display: table;
}
```

```js
$('#list_row1').on('click', function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#table1').addClass('active');
});
```

To avoid repetition, however, you'd be better off extending this this to add `data-*` attributes to your `#list_row/n/` elements, and handle click events on these:

```
<elem id="list_row1" data-row="1"></elem>
```

```js
$('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).attr('data-row');

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#table' + row).addClass('active');
});
```

---

Do also note that you can chain selectors with commas. Rather than using `$(elem1).hide(); $(elem2).hide()` you can instead `$(elem1, elem2).hide()`.

Comment: So first I will put ".active {display: table;}" inside an css file. Then add "display: none" in every table like this:      
 
<div id="table1" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="table2" style="display:none;"></div>
etc..
Is this correct?

Comment: @DlerHasan well a much better solution would be to give your `#table/n/` elements a class which sets them to `display: none` by default.

Comment: Okey, what I have done right now is to add a class in each line with "class = "table", then in css I have wrote ".table{display:none}", but when I run the code by opening "inspect element", I can see that only one display can be active at once.. So if I have ".table{display:none}" and ".table{display:table}", it will run only display:none and not display:block, even if I click on the buttoms..

Comment: @DlerHasan I specified `display: table` in my answer because I assumed `#table/n/` was an `ID` attribute on a `table` element. As you're using `div` elements, you can change your `.active` selector to apply `display: block` instead.

Comment: You assumed right, table1 is an ID. 
<div id="table1" class="table"></div>
<div id="table2" class="table"></div>
<div id="table3" class="table"></div>

And this is my list:
<div id='list_row1' data-row="1"><li class="list-group-item">table1</li></div>
<div id='list_row2' data-row="2"><li class="list-group-item">table2</li></div>

There is just some funky things going on when I click on a specific row.. I am going to research it, but the problem lies that display:block is overwritten by display:none. Sorry for asking so easy questions, I am still learning Javascript.

Comment: I found out the problem, this is what I added in my css file: ".table {display:none;}" and ".table.active{display: block; }". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('[id^=list_row]').on('click',function(){ 
            $('table').hide();
            $('#table'+$(this).attr('id').slice(8)).show();     
});
```

Comment: Works but would have false positives if there are other item IDs that also start with `list_row`. The hard coded slice to eight is also kind of brittle

Comment: Add an `if(/list_row[1-9]\d?/.test(this.id))` in the event. And @JuanMendes's limitation is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [starts-with](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_beginning_value.asp) jQuery selector:

```
$('id^="table"').hide();

$('id^="list_row"').on('click',function(){
    var num = this.id.split('w')[1]; //alert(num)
    $('id^="table"').hide();
    $('#table'+num).show();
});
```

Reference:

[All jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: This approach would mean that no other elements may have an `ID` attribute which begins with "table" or "list_row". What if all the table elements were wrapped in a `#table-container`, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all your table and listrow elements, and a custom attribute on those lasts to identify where are you clicking.

```
<table id="table2" class="tableClass">
<whatever id="list_row2" class="listRowClass" data-yourProjectname-numRow="2">
```

This way you can just show the table that's been clicked and hide all the rest:

```
$(".listRowClass").on("click", function() {
    $(".tableClass").hide() // Hides all tables
    $("#table" + $(this).attr("data-yourProjectname-numRow")).show() //Shows clicked table
});
```